# Azure Automation in Terraform DSC Configuration vs Node Configuration

Tags: azure, terraform, dsc

#### Background

I am trying to use Azure Automation to configure some Azure Windows VMs as DNS servers.

I would like to use Terraform to configure the Automation Account, DSC Configuration and DSC Node Configuration, but I'm stuck on the DSC Node Configuration.

I have the following, which works, but only if I manually compile it by clicking in the Portal:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_dsc_configuration" "configuration" {
    name                    = "DNSConfig"
    resource_group_name     = "my_rg"
    location                = "uksouth"
    automation_account_name = "my_aa_account"
    content_embedded = <<-CONTENT
        Configuration DNSConfig
        {
            Node 'localhost'
            {
                WindowsFeature DNS
                {
                    Ensure = 'Present'
                    Name   = 'DNS'
                }

                # plus some more stuff

            }
        }

    CONTENT
}
```

I want to automate the compilation, so I tried:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_dsc_nodeconfiguration" "node" {
    automation_account_name = "my_aa_account"
    resource_group_name     = "my_rg"
    name                    = "DNSConfig.localhost"
    content_embedded        = "# what goes here?"
}
```

#### Problem

I don't have a strong background with this, so am not sure I have understood it properly. I don't know what `content_embedded` for the `nodeconfiguration` is supposed to contain.

Should I remove the `Node` block from the `dsc_configuration` and move it into the `dsc_nodeconfiguration`? Or perhaps the *contents* of the node block (i.e. excluding the `Node 'localhost' {}` wrapper)?

(I am not really sure if "localhost" is even a good name for what the node represents).

For example, something like:

```
resource "azurerm_automation_dsc_nodeconfiguration" "node" {
    content_embedded = "Node 'localhost' { WindowsFeature DNS {...} }"
    ...
}
```

or

```
resource "azurerm_automation_dsc_nodeconfiguration" "node" {
    content_embedded = "WindowsFeature DNS {...}"`
    ...
}
```

or something else?

I feel like I have tried a few of these options but the feedback loop is pretty slow so it's possible I hit the right answer and got tripped up by another mistake whilst I was debugging!

Does anyone have a working example please or can perhaps explain how it works?

Comment: Have since come across [this Github issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/7404). Perhaps want I want to do is not yet possible.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `content_embedded` you should include the content of MOF file, see [an example](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/website/docs/r/automation_dsc_nodeconfiguration.html.markdown) from `azurerm_automation_dsc_nodeconfiguration` document.
Or you can use terraform [file function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html) to load the MOF content and use it your script. Remember to have the MOF content encoded in either Unicode or UTF-8 format.